# Make QTableView editable when model is pandas dataframe

Tags: python, qt, pandas, pyside, qtableview

In my gui file I create a QTableView as follows (this is the part that is automatically generated by Qt Designer):

```
self.pnl_results = QtGui.QTableView(self.tab_3)
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setPointSize(7)
self.pnl_results.setFont(font)
self.pnl_results.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
self.pnl_results.setFrameShadow(QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
self.pnl_results.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
self.pnl_results.setShowGrid(True)
self.pnl_results.setSortingEnabled(True)
self.pnl_results.setCornerButtonEnabled(True)
self.pnl_results.setObjectName("pnl_results")
```

I then define a model that enables me to link the pandas dataframe to the QTableView:

```
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    """
    Class to populate a table view with a pandas dataframe
    """

    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.values[index.row()][index.column()])
        return None

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]
        return None

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role != QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
            return False
        row = index.row()
        if row < 0 or row >= len(self._data.values):
            return False
        column = index.column()
        if column < 0 or column >= self._data.columns.size:
            return False
        self._data.values[row][column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super(self.__class__,self).flags(index)
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return flags
```

and finally a add my pandas dataframe (df) to the model:

```
model = PandasModel(df)
self.ui.pnl_results.setModel(model)
```

This correctly displays my pandas dataframe in the QTableView. However, for some reason when I edit the fileds the return to their original values (and also once I edit the field it is starting as empty). How can I make it editable and then write the reults back to the pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model lacks [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) method. The default implementation from `QtCore.QAbstractTableModel` does nothing and returns `False`. You need to  implement this method in your model to make its items editable. If `df` is the actual container storing the data, you should simply change the value of the item stored in the container in `setData` method. It could look like this:

```
def setData(self, index, value, role):
    if not index.isValid():
        return False
    if role != QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        return False
    row = index.row()
    if row < 0 or row >= len(self._data.values):
        return False
    column = index.column()
    if column < 0 or column >= self._data.columns.size:
        return False
    self._data.values[row][column] = value
    self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
    return True
```

You also need to implement [flags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html#flags) method to return a value containing `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable`.

Comment: could you make an example how the setData method would have to look like?

Comment: Ok, added the example implementation.

Comment: I have altered my question to the latest version, the problem is that the edited fileds don't seem to propagate to the dataframe and once I hit enter the values are returned to the original ones

Comment: It appears this next problem is specific to that "pandas dataframe" thing. In the related questions I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39971773/1217285) note. Try this and see if t helps.

Comment: @Dimitry: the model in the link seems to work, just not sure why it has checkboxes in every field. How can I get rid of them? is there any flag for that?

Comment: Could you please upload a screenshot with what you observe somewhere? I'm not sure what kind of checkboxes you mean.

Comment: I've posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232314/pandas-df-in-editable-qtableview-flags-remove-check-boxes

Comment: Great, this works flawlessly for me, however what would i have to do to have index?

Comment: Well, you can create one using model's `index` method and pass the desired row and column there.

Comment: @Dmitry I am not an expert in PyQt, so could you please show an example?

Comment: @Dmitry That said, should I ask a question?

Comment: I would suggest to read QAbdtractItemModel's documentation instead of asking it as a separate question. For table models it's a really simple thing. I'm not in front of a computer and won't be until tomorrow so I'm not in position to give a detailed example. But I am sure you can find enough similar examples around here.

Comment: @Dmitry I looked in the documentation however I still can't solve it.

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry to ask you again, when the tableview is edited how can i edit the dataframe too?

Comment: @Dmitry I posted a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353056/how-do-i-edit-the-actual-dataframe-when-i-edit-the-qtableview-data-pyqt5

Answer (score 0):

```
    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
    if index.isValid():
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iat[index.row(),index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
    return False
```

> self._data.values[row][column] = value

didn't work for me, but changing with iat worked