# Pandas df in editable QTableView: remove check boxes

Tags: python, pandas, model, pyside, qtableview

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to present in a QtableView and make it editable. I have create the below model, but for some reason the output has checkboxes in every field. How can I get rid of them?

The outout looks like this:
[image]

And this this is the model that is used to make the pandas dataframe shown in a qtavleview and make it editable (I'm using PySide)

```
class PandasModelEditable(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self._data.values)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole or role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
                return unicode(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
        return unicode()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return '%s' % unicode(self._data.columns.tolist()[section])
            except (IndexError,):
                return unicode()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                return '%s' % unicode(self._data.index.tolist()[section])
            except (IndexError,):
                return unicode()

    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | \
               QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            if self.data(index, QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole) == value:
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
                return True
        return unicode()
```

Removing `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable` does not solve the problem as it doesn't seem to have any effet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning the wrong default values from `data` and `setaData`. The former should return `None` (so you could just remove the last line), whilst the latter should return `False`.

Comment: That solved the problem indeed. Any explanation why this results in such unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @nickpick. The `data` method returns a `QVariant`, so Qt will just convert it to whatever value is appropriate for the given role. An empty string converts to zero, which is equivalent to `Qt.Unchecked`.

Comment: I have tried to point to a a problem I have with this code, but this response has been deleted here, so I have opened up a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743509/editable-qtableview-and-pandas-does-not-work-properly